# Connecting Php to MongoDB using Slim Framework in NetBeans

Tags: php, mongodb, netbeans, slim

I just downloaded and installed Slim to my Php Project and I have been trying to use it to connect to a MongoDB that I have. I know how to connect it to mysql and I saw numerous examples online, but I do not know how to connect it to mongodb. I did it through php without slim and it worked fine and I could query data, so I'm trying to do the same thing using Slim. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Try this code:
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/listdata', 'showData');
$app->post('/create', 'addData');
$app->run();

function addData()
{
// connect
    $m = new MongoClient();
// select your database
    $db = $m->dbname;
// select your collection
    $collection = $db->collectionname;
// add a record
    $document = array("title" => "title 1", "author" => "author 1");
    $collection->insert($document);
// add another record
    $document = array("title" => "title 2", "author" => "author 2");
    $collection->insert($document);
}

function showData()
{
// connect
    $m = new MongoClient();
// select your database
    $db = $m->dbname;
// select your collection
    $collection = $db->collectionname;
// find everything in the collection
    $cursor = $collection->find();
// Show the result here
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        echo $document["title"] . "\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: shouldn't $m = new MongoClient(); be defined as a global variable so that the connection only occurs once ?